# Files are getting created as folder in zip_folder

Tags: python, databricks, zip

I'm trying to create a zip folder with a `.txt` file in it. But when I open `test_20210616.zip`, `test` is available as a folder and not as a `.txt` file.

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile('/dbfs/Test/test_20210616.zip', 'w', allowZip64 = True) as z:
  z.write('/dbfs/Test/','test.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs of zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) the function `ZipFile.write` looks as follows

> ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None, compresslevel=None)

Since you are calling it with `z.write('/dbfs/Test/','test.txt')` you are writing the folder `/dbfs/Test/` into the zip file and giving it the name `text.txt`

Simply pass the whole path to the file as the first argument.